# Dynamic Generation of Rows in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am creating a Data Entry Form having a ComboBox & Few TextBoxes in First Row. I want a new Row with same Elements to be Generated on Pressing Enter Key from Last TextBox in First Row.
How do i achieve it? Is there any Data Template or Item Template or anything as such that can work for this Data Entry Form.
I also read about Observable Collection Class & IEnumerable, can this help me achieving? How?
I am Newbie to WPF & MVVM, have done a lot of research but couldn't find the exact solution.
I have already done this,

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="420">
<Grid Name="_mainGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="227"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="77" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="77" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="27"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Also my .CS Code is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        int rowIndex, Dr = 0, Cr = 0;
        TextBox PTextBox, DrAmtTextBox, CrAmtTextBox;
        ComboBox Combobox;
        List<TextBox> txtboxParticulars = new List<TextBox>();
        List<TextBox> txtboxDrAmount = new List<TextBox>();
        List<TextBox> txtboxCrAmount = new List<TextBox>();
        List<ComboBox> cmbboxDrCr = new List<ComboBox>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateRow();
        }
        public void CreateRow()
        {
            RowDefinition newRow = new RowDefinition();
            newRow.Height = new GridLength(30, GridUnitType.Pixel);
            _mainGrid.RowDefinitions.Insert(_mainGrid.RowDefinitions.Count - 1, newRow);
            rowIndex = _mainGrid.RowDefinitions.Count - 2;
            AddComboBox();
            AddPTextBox();
            AddDrCrTextBox();                        
        }

        public void AddComboBox()
        {
            Combobox = new ComboBox();
            Combobox.Items.Add("Dr.");
            Combobox.Items.Add("Cr.");
            Combobox.SelectedItem = "Dr.";
            Combobox.Height = 25;
            Combobox.Name = "DrCr" + rowIndex.ToString();
            Combobox.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(Combobox_SelectionChanged);
            Combobox.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(Combobox_KeyUp);
            Grid.SetRow(Combobox, rowIndex);
            Grid.SetColumn(Combobox, 0);
            _mainGrid.Children.Add(Combobox);
            cmbboxDrCr.Add(new ComboBox { Text = Combobox.Name });
            cmbboxDrCr[rowIndex].Text = "Dr.";
            Combobox.Focus();
        }

        void Combobox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Combobox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Dr.")
            {
                cmbboxDrCr[rowIndex].Text = "Dr.";
                DrAmtTextBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                CrAmtTextBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            }
            else
            {
                cmbboxDrCr[rowIndex].Text = "Cr.";
                DrAmtTextBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                CrAmtTextBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }

        void Combobox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Combobox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Dr.")
            {
                cmbboxDrCr[rowIndex].Text = "Dr.";
                DrAmtTextBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                CrAmtTextBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                PTextBox.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                cmbboxDrCr[rowIndex].Text = "Cr.";
                DrAmtTextBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                CrAmtTextBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                PTextBox.Focus();
            }
        }

        public void AddPTextBox()
        {
            PTextBox = new TextBox();
            PTextBox.Name = "Particulars" + rowIndex.ToString();
            PTextBox.Height = 25;
            PTextBox.Width = 225;
            Grid.SetRow(PTextBox, rowIndex);
            Grid.SetColumn(PTextBox, 1);
            _mainGrid.Children.Add(PTextBox);
            txtboxParticulars.Add(new TextBox { Text = PTextBox.Name });            
        }

        public void AddDrCrTextBox()
        {
            DrAmtTextBox = new TextBox();
            DrAmtTextBox.Name = "Dr" + rowIndex.ToString();
            DrAmtTextBox.Height = 25;
            DrAmtTextBox.Width = 75;
            DrAmtTextBox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(DrCrAmtTextBox_KeyDown);
            Grid.SetRow(DrAmtTextBox, rowIndex);
            Grid.SetColumn(DrAmtTextBox, 2);
            _mainGrid.Children.Add(DrAmtTextBox);
            txtboxDrAmount.Add(new TextBox { Text = DrAmtTextBox.Name });
            CrAmtTextBox = new TextBox();
            CrAmtTextBox.Name = "Cr" + rowIndex.ToString();
            CrAmtTextBox.Height = 25;
            CrAmtTextBox.Width = 75;
            CrAmtTextBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            CrAmtTextBox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(DrCrAmtTextBox_KeyDown);
            Grid.SetRow(CrAmtTextBox, rowIndex);
            Grid.SetColumn(CrAmtTextBox, 3);
            _mainGrid.Children.Add(CrAmtTextBox);
            txtboxCrAmount.Add(new TextBox { Text = DrAmtTextBox.Name });
        }

        void DrCrAmtTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                AddDataToList();
                CountDrCr();
                CreateRow();
            }
        }
        void CountDrCr()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= rowIndex; i++)
            {
                if (cmbboxDrCr[i].Text == "Dr.")
                {
                    Dr++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Cr++;
                }
            }
        }
        void AddDataToList()
        {
            cmbboxDrCr[rowIndex].Text = Combobox.Text;
            txtboxParticulars[rowIndex].Text = PTextBox.Text;
            txtboxDrAmount[rowIndex].Text = CrAmtTextBox.Text;
            txtboxCrAmount[rowIndex].Text = DrAmtTextBox.Text;
            MessageBox.Show(cmbboxDrCr[rowIndex].Text +" "+ txtboxParticulars[rowIndex].Text + " " + txtboxDrAmount[rowIndex].Text + " " + txtboxCrAmount[rowIndex].Text);
        }

    }
}
```

I know this is not the Right way, so please help me with WPF MVVM method of doing this!!!

After going through the Answers here i have done the Following

- Created a DataType

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;

  namespace DataTemplate
  {
      class YourDataType
      {
          public string DrCr { get; set; }
          public string Particulars { get; set; }
          public float Amount { get; set; }
          public string Narration { get; set; }
      }
  }
  ```
- MainWindow.Xaml File

  ```
  <Window x:Class="DataTemplate.MainWindow"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataTemplate"
      Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="750">
  <Grid>
      <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}">
          <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:YourDataType}">
                  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                          <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0">
                              <ComboBoxItem Content="Dr."/>
                              <ComboBoxItem Content="Cr."/>
                          </ComboBox>
                          <TextBox Width="350"/>
                          <TextBox Width="150"/>
                      </StackPanel>
                      <Label Content="Narration"/>
                      <TextBox Width="450"/>
                  </StackPanel>
              </DataTemplate>
          </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      </ListBox>
  </Grid>
  ```
- MainWindow.CS File

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Windows;
  using System.Windows.Controls;
  using System.Windows.Data;
  using System.Windows.Documents;
  using System.Windows.Input;
  using System.Windows.Media;
  using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
  using System.Windows.Navigation;
  using System.Windows.Shapes;
  using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

  namespace DataTemplate
  {
      /// <summary>
      /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
      /// </summary>
      public partial class MainWindow : Window
      {
          private ObservableCollection<YourDataType> YourCollection;
          public MainWindow()
          {
              InitializeComponent();
              YourCollection.Add(new YourDataType());
          }
       }
    }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

> While it may seem natural for a non WPF developer to build their UI in code, that is generally *not* how it is done in WPF. Learn to do it in XAML and you will save yourself *many* headaches.

First create a data type, let's call it `YourDataType` for example, that contains all of the required properties for each 'row'. Then declare an `ObservableCollection<YourDataType>` property to data bind to a collection control, let's call it `YourCollection`. Finally, declare a `DataTemplate` that defines what each row should look like:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourPrefix:YourDataType}">
            <!-- Define your 'row' controls here -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Now to add a new empty row, all you need to do is to add a new item to your data bound collection:

```
YourCollection.Add(new YourDataType());
```

For further information, please refer to the [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: I did the way as you said, but still its not returning anything on screen. I have updated the Question with my Code now, please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a WPF User Control with the complete structure inside (the comboBoxand and the textboxes), you can create a single list of this usercontrol

for example you can create a FormRow.xaml user control similar to this one....

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFTEST.FormRow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-    compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Width="500" Height="26">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Margin="0"/>
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0"/>
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0"/>
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Grid.Column="3" Margin="0"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And you can add events and control the model object information from the codebehind.....

in the main window you can have a listView or a Stack full of instances of this single control each instance is a view to a model object and preserves the acess hierarchy....

Comment: I have updated the Code, can you lookout where am i doing mistake, because i have tried all possible ways but somehow i am not able to achieve the same in MVVM.